# moving large data between postgresql tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with two fields each in a PostgreSQL 12.4 database.

table_one (id serial, rec text) - 10 mil recs
table_two (id serial, rec jsonb)

I need to move data from table_one to table_two and transform the text into jsonb.

This method worked fairly well until the number of records got to around 400k.

`INSERT INTO table_one(rec) SELECT rec::jsonb FROM table_two;`

I tried the following two copy commands, but ran into syntax errors with both

```
COPY (SELECT item_records::jsonb FROM mdm_impt_json_raw_text) TO mdm_impt_json_raw;
COPY mdm_impt_json_raw(item_records) FROM (SELECT item_records::jsonb FROM mdm_impt_json_raw_text);
```

Could someone either help me with the syntax errors on the copy commands or suggest a better method for moving the data.

Comment: What happened to the fairly well working method around 400k records? Do you do this copy on a regular basis? If so, maybe it can be avoided. Could the first table's text column simply be altered to jsonb?

Comment: I don't see any syntax error in your topic, is it a classified message?

Comment: @Schwern at 400k it takes about 4 min, which if I need to process 15m records will take a really long time. At 500k it is not completing in 15 min.

Comment: @Schwern I tried converting the column to jsonb. Good idea, but at 22 min it is still not completed. `ALTER TABLE mdm_impt.mdm_impt_json_raw_text ALTER COLUMN item_records TYPE jsonb USING item_records::jsonb;`

Comment: @Hilo Yes, parsing 400K text records into JSON can get expensive. If you let the alter table complete it won't have to do that again.